# Inconsistent age range size in 2016 survey report

Tags: bug, status-declined, survey-2016

There is a problem with the way [the survey](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/03/stack-overflow-developer-survey-results/) is reported: [ages in section IV](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016#developer-profile-age). Age are represented in 5-year bands up to 40, after which they're reported in 10-year bands. This skews the chart to artificially lead the reader to believe there are more developers in those age ranges than there actually are. You need to not change the banding - put it all in 5-year bands, or all in 10-year bands, but you can't do both and be believable.

This same problem reappears in the portrayal of Female Developer Age.

This same problem appears in Work, section VII. Salary.

A similar problem occurs in the Experience tab of section VII. Salary, wherein those with less experience are weighted more heavily in terms of the graphical elements allotted to them.

*EDIT*: I'm adding an example of how the data is presented now (well - mine's vertical, rather than horizontal, because I think it's more readable that way) and an example of how it could have been displayed (made up the data from what was there, so the elements in question sum up to what was presented).

[image: Demonstration of skew in reporting]

When doing a first take of the graph at bottom, I have more of a feel for just how skewed the workforce is towards those below 40.  When I look at the one above, I somehow feel that the older age bands aren't so underrepresented, even though I know this intellectually to be untrue.

Comment: It may be hot, and now has a comment (well, two now), but why are there no answers? It would seem that re-munching the data would be a fairly straightforward thing to do....

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet Given that there are 55,000-odd sets of 50-odd responses? Don't think so...

Comment: This non-consistent banding is intentional to trick some redditor into posting something foolish only to get a million imaginary internet points for pointing out that the foolish redditor is foolish. That must be it.

Comment: When I read that chart, I believed that there are a 8.9% share in the age range 40-49. Now I'm told that I got tricked and the chart is not believable. Which is the right figure? Please OP, share your knowledge and continue to always protect us ignorant that can't read a table and are (maybe intentionally?) lead to believe that every programmer in SO is older than 40.

Comment: @nicola - I suppose you've read Tufte, graphs can be misleading, and not everybody reads tables.

Comment: @nicola - it's visually misleading, and gives less detail for the higher age ranges than it gives for the younger, leading to a weaker report; your sarcasm, there, doesn't seem aimed at the discussion, but at the poster, and is uncalled for.

Comment: @ArtOfCode - munching the data, given that you'd 1) stored the data sensibly, and 2) saved your queries, should be incredibly trivial; 55,000 rows of age data is nothing, to a database like SQL Server or Oracle or even to MySQL.

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet Sorry for the sarcasm, you were right in saying that it wasn't aimed at the discussion. I apologize for that. However, maybe it's just me, but I can't see how it is misleading. The legend is clean, the numbers are clearly visible and what they represent is pretty obvious. I really don't agree on "lead the reader to believe there are more developers in those age ranges". Why is that? I guess that I'm might be pretty ignorant on this aspect, but can't see how a programmer or anybody that actually see the graph misrepresents its results.

Comment: @nicola It's what we would ordinarily call a dirty trick, to change the graph in such a way as to be visually deceiving.  On first glance, it says one thing, and only by reading further do you get some idea of what's really being said.  Even then, though, that first impression has been made, and forms an anchor for how you perceive the results.

Comment: @nicola What I'm pointing out is that by adding 2 more bars to the charts they would not be being deceptive, and would have a much less dubious presentation.  To me, lumping things together like this makes me ask questions about why it was done - was it to obscure things, for example.  I doubt that's the case - it's probably just nicer looking to have 5 bars instead of 7 - but it isn't good practice for the presentation of statistics, and should be fixed.

Comment: As Sam said in his answer we simply do not have the data for a better breakdown. We will do better in the next survey. Adding [meta-tag:status-declined].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good catch. We never intended to be deceiving. The age ranges displayed are just an artifact of how we asked this question in previous years, with less granularity in certain age ranges than others.

So actually, we can't tell you how many respondents are in their low-40s and how many are in their high-40s. We can only tell you how many are in their 40s. So if we were to re-do the chart so that all ranges are equal, we'd have to collapse the 20s and 30s, giving us a chart that looks like this:

[image]

One interesting takeaway from this presentation: more than half of all respondents are in their 20s. You couldn't tell that from the way we laid out the chart this year. Next year we should probably reformulate the question to get more granular age data.

Comment: It might be an idea to allow a specific age, a range, or none - rather than just a range or none. I'd imagine a decent amount of people wouldn't mind disclosing their exact age

Comment: You know, that's actually kind of an awesome graph, there, with everything banded equally!  It makes it really clear just how skewed towards the youngsters this really is.

Comment: I agree with @Rob above: people would probably be willing to give an exact age (although obviously not their birthdates), which would allow you to present the data as area beneath a curve, with standard-deviation lines to indicate where the breaks are in the data.

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet yeah, I'm inclined to allow for exact age (integers) next year. The main restriction for questions is usually cognitive load, but I think an age dropdown or age free response is probably as user-friendly as any other way to ask this question.